# How to get test dependencies to show up in maven pom when they are added via a plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, maven-publish

I have a project that uses buildSrc to create a plugin to avoid duplicate logic, one of this type of duplicate is test dependencies.

I notice that when we publish the jar that the test dependencies are not included in the pom file.  I tried modifying the versionMapping but can't find a solution to get the dependencies added

tried

```
versionMapping {
  allVariants {
    fromResolutionOf('testRuntimeClasspath')
  }
}
```

but see the test dependencies are still not found.

The buildSrc plugin defines the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testImplementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}
```

How do I get these dependencies to show up in the published pom?

Thanks!

Edit: The main reason we want this is to act as documentation on how to use the -tests.jar also published, as the main consumer of this library uses -tests.jar for testing

Comment: Why would you need them? For downstream consumers of your project, they don't care how exactly you tested it. From their perspective, the tests have already been run and passed.

Comment: we also publish the test jar as the main consumer needs that for extra testing, so it also acts as documentation what is needed for the test jar to work fully

Comment: That's not how test jars work. `test` scope dependencies are not transitive, even for test jars. If you want that behaviour, make a first-class module for the shared stuff called eg. "test-utils" and depend upon that in both places with `test` scope.

Comment: If you want them published in the pom, despite it not being good practice, change `testImplementation` to just plain `implementation`.